# Yii2 migration cant create DataBase

Tags: yii2, migration

I create a table with migration and all works. But when i try yii migrate i catch error "database doesn exist". When i try to create DB in php admin, and after it use yii migrate, all works, tables was add to my db. 
P.S db connection file work.

```
 return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=splynx',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

I Ask, how migrate can create DB?

Comment: You have to create database beforehand. If there is no database you can not connect to it as you try with your database credentials (`dbname=splynx`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use migrations on a table you HAVE TO create the database before that and then put the database with credentials in your DB file. then you will be able to use migrations.

You cannot migrate on a database which does not actually exist, as the error clearly says.

Answer (score 0):

You can use migration to create rename tables but not create DB. Migration need to configure access to existing DB.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, create a database in localhost named splynx and then run the migrations